# Filter for the first 3 rows, but when there is a tie in the score of the third place, pick one randomly

Tags: r

I am working with R and I have data that looks like this...

```
structure(list(Condition = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), Primary = c("love", 
"love", "love", "love", "love", "place", "place", "place", "place", 
"place", "park", "park", "park", "park", "park", "hill", "hill", 
"hill", "hill", "hill", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool", 
"bike", "bike", "bike", "bike", "bike"), Secondary = c("trail", 
"surprise", "elegant", "instinct", "person", "car", "amid", "sentiment", 
"family", "sensation", "affect", "effective", "ground", "hug", 
"punch", "maze", "amicable", "fierce", "measure", "thankful", 
"like", "smile", "wish", "ask", "humble", "stress", "happiness", 
"flat", "bed", "sky"), Score = c(0.09, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 
0.3, 0.12, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.2, 0.11, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.18, 
0.07, 0.07, 0.05, 0.05, 0.25, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.25, 0.14, 
0.11, 0.07, 0.06), Condition2 = c("CM", "CM", "CL", "CL", "CL", 
"CM", "CM", "CM", "CL", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CL", "CM", NA, 
"CL", "CM", "CL", "CM", NA, "CM", "CM", "CL", "CL", "CM", "CM", 
"CM", "CL", "CL"), place = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), preference = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", NA, "2", "1", 
"2", "1", NA, "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to filter for the first 3 rows. However, sometimes there is a tie in the third place. This means that the score (in Score column) is the same and therefore in reality they occupay the third place. For example...

```
Condition  Primary    Secondary     Score  Condition2  Place  Preference
1          place      car           0.30      CM         1       1
1          place      amid          0.12      CM         2       1
1          place      sentiment     0.03      CM         3       1
1          place      family        0.03      CL         4       2
1          place      sensation     0.03      CM         5       1
```

So, what I need to do is to filter for the first 3 places, but when there is a tie, like in the above example, I need to pick one randomly.

How can I filter for the first three but when there is a tie in the score of the 3 place, pick one of them randomly.

Thanks

Comment: Could you just use the rank function with ties.method = "random" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that can work. First, create a column with ties.method set to random and then one new column set to "first" and the filter. Thanks.